# How to layout yii2 form fields side by side

Tags: yii, yii2

I would like to place form fields in Yii2 side by side, in a 2x2 grid.

I'm using the bootstrap/ActiveForm as such

```
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'layout' => 'horizontal',
    'action' => ['index'],
    'method' => 'get',
    'fieldConfig' => [
        'horizontalCssClasses' => [
            'label' => 'col-sm-2',
            'offset' => 'col-sm-offset-2',
            'wrapper' => 'col-sm-4',
        ],
    ],
]); ?>
```

The fields are basically a series of date widgets

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'saleFrom')->widget(DatePicker::className(), [
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'TO'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'autoclose' => true,
        'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd'
    ]
]); ?>
```

However all that has managed to do is align all four fields to the left of the div - i can't figure out from the documentation how to use the Yii2 options to do this without having to manually add custom css.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All you need is to wrap your form columns in another bootstrap `row`.

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'layout' => 'horizontal',
    'action' => ['index'],
    'method' => 'get',
    'fieldConfig' => [
        'horizontalCssClasses' => [
            'label' => 'col-sm-2',
            'offset' => 'col-sm-offset-2',
            'wrapper' => 'col-sm-4',
        ],
    ],
]); ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'firstname') ?>
            <?= $form->field($model, 'lastname') ?>
       </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <?= $form->field($model, 'email') ?>
            <?= $form->field($model, 'bla') ?>
       </div>
    </div>
<?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

Comment: this doesn't work because the yii2 markup adds its own bootstrap stuff- thats why i need to understand yii2's usage of bootstrap

Comment: Of course it *does* work - did you even try it? Yii only creates the markup for `form-group`. You can nest these inside grid columns however you want. I do this constantly throughout my projects.

Comment: Well i did try it and it changed literally nothing

Comment: Then you must already have messed up something. Just tried again with a clean new Yii app template. I've changed the login form - works like a charm.

Comment: Have u tried it in a partial view file that is included in a larger index type page?

Comment: If that does not work, then you've again messed up your grid somehwere, e.g. forgot to start a new `row` and `col-...` or something. You can [nest](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting) columns however you want. The solution I've showed always works as long as you don't break bootstrap's grid. All this is not really Yii related, as Yii does nothing special in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap grid for build the the layout you prefer

```
<div class="site-index">
    <div class="body-content">
        <div class='col-sm-6 col-md-6' id='id'>
        <?php 
                $form1 = ActiveForm::begin([
                    'layout' => 'horizontal',
                    'action' => ['index1'],
                    'method' => 'get',
                    'fieldConfig' => [
                        'horizontalCssClasses' => [
                            'label' => 'col-sm-2',
                            'offset' => 'col-sm-offset-2',
                            'wrapper' => 'col-sm-4',
                        ],
                    ],
                ]); 

                ... 
        ?>

        </div>
        <div class='col-sm-6 col-md-6' id='id2'>

                $form2 = ActiveForm::begin([
                    'layout' => 'horizontal',
                    'action' => ['index2'],
                    'method' => 'get',
                    'fieldConfig' => [
                        'horizontalCssClasses' => [
                            'label' => 'col-sm-2',
                            'offset' => 'col-sm-offset-2',
                            'wrapper' => 'col-sm-4',
                        ],
                    ],
                ]); 

                ... 
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want 2 activeforms, i need 1 with four fields in grid.  I thought yii had options to do it in the activeform rather than have to set up the bootstrap divs?

Comment: There are extensions for this  .. but i think the simple grid with bootstrap is often very convenient